# What will cause MKMapView to change it's userTrackingMode?

Tags: ios, mkmapview

In `viewDidLoad` method I've set userTrackingMode to `MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading`.
After adding some annotations and overlays to mapview,mapview delegate method `mapView:didChangeUserTrackingMode:animated:` gets fired .Then mapview userTrackingMode gets back to `MKUserTrackingModeFollow` . Why?

Here is the code:

```
.......
    [self.pMapView addOverlay: self.pPolyline];
.......
    [self.pMapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

I did remove some annotations, but I did not remove userLocation.

```
- (void) removeAllAnnotationsExceptUserLocationAndDestinAnnotation
{
    for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in [[self.pMapView.annotations copy] autorelease])
    {
        if ([annotation isMemberOfClass: [MKUserLocation class]]) continue;

        CLLocationDegrees anLat = [self latitudeOfDestination];
        CLLocationDegrees anLon = [self longitudeOfDestination];

        if (anLat == annotation.coordinate.latitude && anLon == annotation.coordinate.longitude)
        {
            continue;
        }

        [self.pMapView removeAnnotation: annotation];
    }
}
```

Comment: are you removing annotations? if so, make sure you are not removing the userLocation annotation.

Comment: why are you copying the annotation array?

Comment: Because while it's looping, some other methods may modify mapview's annotations,it's for thread safety.